# How do I turn a Render of a 3D Model into this flat / vector style in Photoshop? (CS6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6, photoshop-effects, flat-design

In Overwatch one of the gamemode icons is this:

[image]

Which is clearly a filtered 3D render, or vector/trace of a 3D render of one of their charcters. I wouldn't think it's unreasonable to assume it's just an applied filter/effect (or a few effects), or that you can get a very close look without tracing the image in a vector program. What can I do in Photoshop CS6  to get the same or a very close look to the image above from a source image?

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted looks similar to the Cutout filter in Photoshop.

Here's an example before and after

[image: Example of cutout filter]